# Geometry nodes - instancing object from collection on specific point/vertex

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm looking to know how we can instance an object on a specific vertex with the geometry node. Basically choose a vertex by its ID to assign it an object or collection instance and do it for each selected vertice.

I'm pretty sure it's possible but I can't find an answer to this question.

Thank you for your time

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer". This will make it easier for others to see which path leads to the solution, and the question will no longer show as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result with the node `Instance on Points`.

In this example I use a cube as the base and an icosphere as the object to be instantiated.

If you use the node `Compare` to compare the current index with a value of your choice, you get an additional selection.

You feed this selection into the node `Instance on Points`, which will instantiate an object exactly at the vertex you have chosen by index.

[image]